# My global IP address is 192.168.1.xxx?

Tags: ip, routing

I am using Ubuntu and found out that my global IP address is `192.168.1.xxx` I wrote it as `xxx` here.

To check this I set up a web server and it could be reached only by this local looking ip address. When I check with what is my IP web page it shows a normal looking IP address: `180.150.80.xxx` And the web page is not reachable from this normal looking IP address. I used my cell phone to check this.

The output from `ip addr` is:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 98:e7:f4:0f:3d:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:81:98:cc:2d:bf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname wlp3s0
    inet 192.168.1.xx/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlo1
       valid_lft 84833sec preferred_lft 84833sec
    inet6 2403:580e:7b3c:0:b69:4100:a7f4:xxxx/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 6707sec preferred_lft 3105sec
    inet6 2403:580e:7b3c:0:1f61:fea0:6275:xxxx/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6707sec preferred_lft 3105sec
    inet6 fe80::a117:ea44:a262:xxxx/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

And the output from IP route is:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.xx metric 600
```

What is going on here?

I am adding a screenshot showing IPv4 address via GUI below:

[image: Screen shot]

Why am I seeing the IP address as `192.168.1.xxx`?

Comment: 192.168.1.xxx absolutely isn’t a public address and cannot be accessed outside of your intranet network. I have the exact same address assigned to my iPhone

Comment: @Ramhound I know 192.168.1 is for local ip addresses because of that reason I post this. What is my global ip address shown there then?

Comment: 180.150.80.xxx exists outside of your network and is impossible for it to exist only internally if the client is connected to the internet. If your web server cannot be accessed by clients external to your network it means you need to forward the port the web service is bound to the server. How you do that is well documented

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your answer. I don't have a web server right now. I am just asking that arent those outputs supposed to show my global ip address. Am I wrong? I can't see it there.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#One-to-many_NAT

Comment: This seems like I am under an additional subnet in my home network somewhow...

Comment: @lid Of course? Especially when you are connected to WiFi. Even with wired Ethernet typically you don't get a public IP assigned on your PC directly, unless you don't need the internet connection to available to anything but this one PC. (And even when that's the case, you'd likely have it in some "additional subnet" just because there are other devices in your home that you want the PC to have access to.) Are you really new to networking stuff? Not really sure why you'd get the feeling of "somehow".

Comment: @lid - “To check this I set up a web server”, I am confused

Comment: @Tom Yan Yes I am new to networking.

Comment: @Ramhound It was a way to check my external ip. Only if you now your external ip you can reach your web page in the web server (after port forwarding in the router). But may be I misremember things. I will check it.

Comment: @lid - It’s unclear what your attempting to do.

Comment: TLDR: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network - anything with 192.168.x.x, 172.16-31.x.x, or 10.x.x.x is a private network and will not route over the internet.   These ranges are setup specifically for private entities to create their own internal routing.   Your gateway at 192.168.1.1 may have a public IP or may route to another private gateway to some point that does have a public IP to eventually make it to the public internet.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> I am using Ubuntu and found out that my global IP address is…

It's not global. Do not pay much attention to `scope global`; that field within 'ip addr' never had any significance to IPv4 entries (and it has lost much of its original meaning even for IPv6 too). If it's an 192.168.x.x address, then it's a private address regardless of the scope parameter.

(IPv4 never really had "scope" as a built-in concept. It's IPv6 that used to have 'scope site' for its original kind of private addresses, but that's now obsolete and the newer kind of private IPv6 addresses just uses 'scope global' as well, so you always have to look at the actual address prefix to determine its type.)

About the only other remaining value that does have significance is 'scope link', which indicates that this address is strictly limited to the subnet. (Unlike private addresses which *can* be routed across many networks and subnets, a link-local address never goes beyond its own subnet.)

| Scope | Practical meaning |
| --- | --- |
| Global | Can be routed without specific boundaries. (Yes, for private addresses there's a boundary, but that boundary is defined by ISP policy, it's not inherent in IP functionality.) |
| Site | Can be routed between interfaces with the same "site ID". (IPv6-only, and obsolete.) |
| Link | Cannot be routed at all; limited to a single subnet. |
| Host | Only ever used within the same computer; a "localhost" address. |

> When I check with what is my ip web page it shows a normal looking ip address:180.150.80.xxx And the web page is not reachable from this normal looking ip address
>
> What is going on here?

What's going on is that (actual global) IPv4 addresses are scarce, and residential ISPs only issue one global address *per customer.* (And these days, often not even that anymore.)

Multiple devices cannot actually "share" the same IP address, so typically that one address is assigned to a router that's capable of NAT (i.e. your home wifi router). The router rewrites all your packets outbound to the Internet so that they appear *as if* they come from the router's public address instead of whatever the computer actually has.

This means that when you try to make an *inbound* connection to your 180.150.80.xxx address, you're always connecting to your router. To host a web server inside, the router needs to be set up to forward that connection somewhere further, most commonly by using NAT again (aka "port forwarding").

It is, however, increasingly common that residential customers no longer get even that single IP address – instead another layer of NAT is done at the ISP itself. In such situations, inbound connections never reach the customer's network at all, and no amount of "port forwarding" will help. So *before* you spend time trying to get it working, open your router's status page and check what IP address it has.

On the bright side, your computer *does* have an **IPv6** address that is actually global. All of the `inet6 2403:580e:[...]` entries should be reachable from outside (although your router may still block inbound connections in its *firewall* configuration), and the address *without* the 'temporary' flag can be used to host servers. As long as all your visitors have IPv6, that is... (most people still don't)

> This seems like I am under an additional subnet in my home network somewhow...

You are under *NAT* in your home network.

Your home network literally is the "additional subnet", but it's not networks or subnets themselves that cause this (not directly, at least); it's the lack of sufficient global IPv4 addresses for all devices in that subnet.

(And, probably, also historical practice even for ISPs which would have had enough of them. Until around two decades ago, many people did not have a "home network" just yet; they would *directly* connect their computer to the ISP – whether via dial-up or via ADSL – and that computer would directly receive a single public address... and so all residential ISPs had their systems architectured to assign just that one address to each customer. When things grew larger, it was probably "more cost-effective" for them do NAT on the customer side than to change how the ISP's own systems worked.)

Beyond home networks, however, it is still normal for a larger (e.g. corporate or university) network to have many public IPv4 addresses routed internally in various ways, and there's no technical relationship between 'private address' and 'subnet'.

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. It is pretty helpful.

Comment: To add to this, just go to `https://icanhazip.com/` to see your ip as the internet sees it. It won't start with 192.168

Comment: They already did, in the 2nd paragraph of the OP.